# Getting only the same result to appear in SQL

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

This is my code, later I will be putting it into php, but for the time being I am using it in a provided Query tester. We are doing the first degree of kevin bacon instead of the 6th.

**My query is as follow:**

```
SELECT name,year
FROM actors
JOIN roles ON roles.actor_id = actors.id
JOIN movies ON movies.id=roles.movie_id
WHERE actors.first_name= 'kevin' AND actors.last_name='bacon' OR actors.first_name= 'sean' AND actors.last_name='penn'
ORDER BY movies.name;
```

**it results in**

```
Animal House 1978
Apollo 13 1995 
Few Good Men, A 1992 
Footloose 1984 
Hollow Man 2000 
JFK 1991 
Mystic River 2003 
Mystic River 2003 
Planes, Trains & Automobiles 1987 
Stir of Echoes 1999
```

**How do I get it to show only Mystic River?**

Comment: You want to know where both Kevin Bacon and Sean Penn are in the same movie right?

Answer (score 1):

First, group the condition

```
WHERE (actors.first_name= 'kevin' AND actors.last_name='bacon') OR 
      (actors.first_name= 'sean' AND actors.last_name='penn')
```

Second, Add `DISTINCT` after the `SELECT` keyword

```
SELECT DISTINCT ...
```

***follow-up question: why do you only want to show `Mystic River`?***

Answer (score 1):

i think wat you are asking for here is DISTINCT...

The DISTINCT keyword can be used to return only distinct (different) values.

try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT name,year
FROM actors
JOIN roles ON roles.actor_id = actors.id
JOIN movies ON movies.id=roles.movie_id
WHERE (actors.first_name= 'kevin' AND actors.last_name='bacon') OR (actors.first_name= 'sean' AND actors.last_name='penn')
ORDER BY movies.name;
```

and THIS in where clause,

```
 WHERE (actors.first_name= 'kevin' AND actors.last_name='bacon') AND (actors.first_name= 'sean' AND actors.last_name='penn')
```

if you want to know where both Kevin Bacon and Sean Penn are in the same movie

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question properly, you are trying to find the list of movies that have `Sean Penn` and `Kevin Bacon` in them. If so, then you would need to use the actors and the roles table twice in your query.

```
SELECT
    movies.name,
    movies.year
FROM
    actors AS actor2 INNER JOIN roles AS role2 ON actor2.ID = role2.actor_id
           INNER JOIN actors AS actor1 INNER JOIN roles AS role1 ON actor1.ID = role1.actor_id
                INNER JOIN movies ON role1.movie_id = movies.ID ON role2.movie_id = movies.ID
WHERE
    actor1.first_name= 'kevin' AND actor1.last_name='bacon'
        AND
    actor2.first_name= 'sean' AND actor2.last_name='penn'
ORDER BY movies.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT name,year
FROM actors
JOIN roles ON roles.actor_id = actors.id
JOIN movies ON movies.id=roles.movie_id
WHERE actors.first_name= 'kevin' AND actors.last_name='bacon' OR actors.first_name= 'sean' AND actors.last_name='penn'
ORDER BY movies.name;
```